# Count number of subsets having a particular XOR value

Tags: algorithm

I came across a XOR related algorithm problem in geeksforgeeks and trying to understand what its doing but unable to understand it.

[Problem link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-of-subsets-having-a-particular-xor-value/) ( Given an array arr[] of n numbers and a number K, find the number of subsets of arr[] having XOR of elements as K )

Can anyone briefly explain what it's doing from the second step and kindly suggest from where to read bit manipulation algorithm technique.

Comment: But this link explains all the process in details. Do you know how `xor` works?

Comment: ya I know, can you explain 3rd step with a suitable example??

Comment: OK, I added example

Comment: Blech, we can do a lot better with linear algebra over Z/2.

Answer (score 2):

3rd step:

Let we consider `j` (xor result) value `5 = 101b` and `arr[i-1] = 3 = 011b`

We can get result `j = 5` by two ways:
-not using `arr[i-1]`, so the first summand is equal to `dp[i­-1][j]`
-using `arr[i-1]`, so the second summand must be taken from
  the cell with xor value (j index) `101b xor 011b = 110b = 6`

```
  for arr[i-1] = 3
  dp[i][5] = dp[i-1][5] + dp[i-1][6]
```